# Problem with Crawling Mechanism of Twitter Python Crawler

Tags: python, html, twitter, web-crawler

Below is a small snippet of code I have for my twitter crawler mechanism:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = 'http://mobile.twitter.com/NYTimesKrugman'

def gettweets(soup):
    tags = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : "list-tweet"})#to obtain tweet of a follower
    for tag in tags: 
        print tag.renderContents()
        print ('\n\n')

def are_more_tweets(soup):#to check whether there is more than one page on mobile   twitter 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id: 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        test_b = str(b)
        if test_b.find('more'):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def getnewlink(soup): #to get the link to go to the next page of tweets on twitter 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id : 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        if str(b) == 'more':
            c = link['href']
            d = 'http://mobile.twitter.com' +c
            return d

def checkforstamp(soup): # the parser scans a webpage to check if any of the tweets are older than 3 months
    times = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {'class': 'status_link'})
    for time in times:
        stamp = time.renderContents()
        test_stamp = str(stamp)
        if test_stamp == '3 months ago':  
            print test_stamp
            return True
        else:
            return False


response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
gettweets(soup)
stamp = checkforstamp(soup)
tweets = are_more_tweets(soup)
print 'stamp' + str(stamp)
print 'tweets' +str (tweets)
while (stamp is False) and (tweets is True): 
    b = getnewlink(soup)
    print b
    red = urllib2.urlopen(b)
    html = red.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    gettweets(soup)
    stamp = checkforstamp(soup)
    tweets = are_more_tweets(soup)
print 'done'
```

The problem is, after my twitter crawler hits about 3 months of tweets, I would like it to stop going to the next page of a user.  However, it does not appear to be doing that. It seems to continually going searching for the next page of tweets. I believe this is due to the fact that checkstamp keeps evaluating to False. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can modify the code so that the crawler keeps looking for the next page of tweets as long as there are more tweets (verified by are_more_tweets mechanism) and it hasn't hit 3 months of tweets yet??? Thanks!

**EDIT** - Please see below:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib

url = 'http://mobile.twitter.com/cleversallie'
output = open(r'C:\Python28\testrecursion.txt', 'a') 

def gettweets(soup):
    tags = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : "list-tweet"})#to obtain tweet of a follower
    for tag in tags: 
        a = tag.renderContents()
        b = str (a)
        print(b)
        print('\n\n')

def are_more_tweets(soup):#to check whether there is more than one page on mobile twitter 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id: 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        test_b = str(b)
        if test_b.find('more'):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def getnewlink(soup): #to get the link to go to the next page of tweets on twitter 
    links = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {id : 'more_link'})
    for link in links:
        b = link.renderContents()
        if str(b) == 'more':
            c = link['href']
            d = 'http://mobile.twitter.com' +c
            return d

 def checkforstamp(soup): # the parser scans a webpage to check if any of the tweets are older than 3 months
    times = soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}, {'class': 'status_link'})
    for time in times:
        stamp = time.renderContents()
        test_stamp = str(stamp)
        if not (test_stamp[0]) in '0123456789':
            continue
        if test_stamp == '3 months ago':
            print test_stamp
            return True
        else:
            return False


response = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
gettweets(soup)
stamp = checkforstamp(soup)
tweets = are_more_tweets(soup)
while (not stamp) and (tweets): 
    b = getnewlink(soup)
    print b
    red = urllib.urlopen(b)
    html = red.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    gettweets(soup)
    stamp = checkforstamp(soup)
    tweets = are_more_tweets(soup)
 print 'done'
```

Comment: As I said in your last question, what does `print test_stamp` __BEFORE__ the `if` statement show? Does it ever show `3 months ago` or anything like that? Also, as I answered your last question correctly, please accept that answer.

Comment: Hi, I apologize. I thought the last post got a bit muddled up so I wanted to clarify in a new question. Your last answer did answer my question. However, it also exposed another deficiency of my code so I thought it would help to create a new post.

Comment: Eek. Not enough space to comment. Are you suggesting that I move the print test_stamp to before the if statement to see if it even picks up something that says 3 months ago? I'm assuming so - so I'm trying to test that.

Comment: Okay, so I did as you suggested - and found this. This is an example of the supposed test_stamp that my program is picking up:<img alt="Twitter" class="logo" src="http://a2.twimg.com/twitter-mobile/790e2b51cfc604c1d2f00cf9b099ac025de7fa5c/images/sprites/logo.gif" />

Comment: Nothing wrong with starting a new question, it's what you're supposed to do. Answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `soup.findall()` is picking up an image tag in a link that matches your pattern (has an `href` attribute and `class` `status-link`).

Instead of always `return`ing on the very first link, try:

```
for time in times:
    stamp = time.renderContents()
    test_stamp = str(stamp)
    print test_stamp
    if not test_stamp[0] in '0123456789':
        continue
    if test_stamp == '3 months ago':  
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Which will skip the link if it doesn't start with a number, so you might actually get to the right link. Keep that `print` statement in there so you can see if you hit some other kind of link that starts with a number that you also need to filter out.

Edit: What you were doing was **always returning** on the **very first** item in `times`. I changed it so it **ignored any links** that didn't start with a number.

However, this would cause it to return `None` if it didn't find **any** links with a number. This would work fine, except you changed `while not stamp and tweets` to `while stamp is False and tweets is True`. Change it back to `while not stamp and tweets` and it will correctly treat `None` and `False` as the same, and it should work.

Comment: I added this code in and discovered something. Because the time stamp in the tweets changes to 'about a month ago', I simply stop picking up tweets at the one month mark rather than the 3 month mark. I believe this is due to the (if not test_stamp[0]..) bit. At least I am getting more than one page of tweets...However, I am not getting enough data. To provide you with some more information...what I ultimately want to do is pick up about 3 months of tweets after February (any time) and about 3 months of tweets before February 2011 for a single user. Can you make any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. When I tested the program with the user NYTimesKrugman, it seemed to function just perfectly. However, when I tested the program with another twitter user, cleversallie, I received the following error message:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Columbia Job/Python Crawler/Twitter Crawler/testingrecursionofsamefollower1.py", line 60, in <module>
    red = urllib2.urlopen(b)
  File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib2.py", line 385, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Comment: Oops, I'm new to stack overflow and didn't realize I should be accepting the answers...Sorry!

Comment: Thanks :). It's a known bug with your version of Python. The easiest thing is probably to try `import urllib` instead of `import urllib2` and use `urllib.urlopen`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to upgrade / downgrade to a different version of python.

Comment: After making all your suggested changes but now adding in urllib instead of urllib2, I am faced with the following error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Columbia Job/Python Crawler/Twitter Crawler/testingrecursionofsamefollower1.py", line 60, in <module>
    red = urllib.urlopen(b)
  File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib.py", line 177, in open
    fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
  File "C:\Python28\lib\urllib.py", line 1038, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: I cannot determine why a none type object is being returned however, given that my code (with the while not stamps and tweets line) would ensure that a new link to the next page of tweets would only be put into urllib.urlopen if there was another page of tweets.

Comment: In `getnewlink(soup)`, if either `soup.findall` is returning an empty list or `link.renderContents()` is never equal to `'More'`, `None` will be returned (if it's still the same as in your post). So you need to put `print` statements back in there to see what's happening, or else `break` out of your `while` if `b` is `None`.

Comment: Hmm, the issue is that if b is none (there are no more links) tweets should be returned as False, breaking out of the while loop (see are_more_tweets) function. However, I don't understand why this is not working...Just to clarify I have edited my above question and pasted my modified code. Thanks.

Comment: We went through this EXACT problem once before on one of your previous questions. `find` returns `-1`, not `0` if it doesn't find anything! So test `if blah.find('bleh') != -1`. And, if you keep the `if` statement like it is, you will return `False` if the VERY FIRST LINK YOU FIND doesn't have `more` in it. Instead, get rid of the `else` and move the `return False` to below the loop so it only returns `False` if it doesn't find `more` in __any__ of the links.